Getting Null pointer exception while creating message
In Guidewire ClaimCenter, I have a custom subtype entity for TransactionSet. Now, I need to send a payload when the user adds some value to that custom subtype entity. This payload needs to be sent through a message queue.
have added all the required setup for the message queue(added event on transactionset entity, message-config-xml defined,etc.).
However, while generating the message (MessageContext.createMessage("")) from an event-fired ruleset, I am getting a Null Pointer Exception. How can I resolve this issue?

We need to see your code to assist. See [mcve] for more information.

I would suggest improving this question by adding the stack trace leading up to the null pointer exception. Also add the code from the gosu rule that you are using to create the message. Lastly I would also reconsider the creation of a custom subtype for TransactionSet. ClaimCenter allows for a lot of customization, but one rule that I always try to abide by is "don't muck with the financials"

Apart from what has been mentioned in the comments, that showing the code and stack trace would help identify the issue, could you try debugging your EventFiredRule? What is the type of messageContext.Root? Is it your subtype of TransactionSet or Transaction? What is the value of messageContext.EventName? And finally, what is the payload you are sending to the createMessage function? Do you have a function to build the payload? You would need to debug it as well and check if you have some errors there.
